# Is there any way to hide this ms(40.1 ms x) information on upper left side? I'm getting it when I run my localhost:300

Tags: ruby

When I run my localhost:3000 I getting this information at the upperleft side it seems to be some duration loading information example 40.1ms x 2. Is there any way to hide this?, it does not affect the functionality but it is blocking the view when I do styling. Hopefully somebody can help.

[View image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U2lY.png)

Comment: That's a browser debugging feature you've accidentally enabled.

Comment: I think is it enabled by default. Any Idea where I can disable this?